# FPDF - Define page for position XY

Tags: php, export, fpdf

I can not define which pages to put my values ​​on with FPDF, SetXY () and $ pdf-> Write

I have a 5-page pdf template that I import, then export and I would like to place variables in separate positions before exporting this file.

ex: How to put the text 'toto' on page 3 of my PDF, or 'titi' on page 5?

Thanks for your help

```
$pdf = new FPDI('P', 'cm', 'A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10); 
$file_name = "export_test.pdf"; 
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("exportPDF/exportRapo.pdf");

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}

$pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
$pdf->Write(0, 'Text de test');

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .$file_name. '"');

readfile($file_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    if($pageNo == 1)
    { 
      $pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
      $pdf->Write(0, 'Toto');
    }

    if($pageNo == 2)
    {
       $pdf->SetXY(10, 20);
       $pdf->Write(0, 'Titi');
    }
    ..........
    ..........
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}
```

According to your current code, this seems to be a way. This seems a little naive, but if somehow you can figure the content for page according to the page no, it would be easier/efficient, rather than putting multiple `if` condditons for each page.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I want! You are a genius :)

Answer (score 0):

[PB : text covered by pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2QaY.png)

Do you know how to pass the text over the pdf and not below? 
In the red box the text should normally read "Municipal Police, 8"

```
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); // noir
    $pdf->AddPage();


    if($pageNo == 1){ 
      $pdf->SetXY(11.5, 85);
      $pdf->Write(0, $recourseOrganizationName.','.$recourseOrganizationStreetNumber);
    }

  $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}
```

Comment: I think this is related to the layout of my word base file that integrates text boxes
because it works on other pages. Thx for help

Comment: I found solution to my problem this was related to the word and the text box, which by passed the text. 
Thank you again for your help